# Android Button Disappear in table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have an application with two activities. `MainActivity` loads an xml(`printscreen.xml`) where there is two buttons(`print` and `close`) and a `webview`. When the application runs it loads the webpage and the two buttons with right positions. When I click the print button it goes to another activity and when I back to the main activity button disappears(some portion of close button).

Here is my `printscreen.xml`file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClose"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn"
                android:text="Close" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPrint"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn"
                android:text="Print" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webViewPrint"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the screenshots of my problem:
First one is when load the application initialy(It is correct). The second one is back to MainActivity(This is incorrect).
[image: Before Go to Another activity]
[image: Back to mainactivity]

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class VividViewerActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
    context = this;
    View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
    setContentView(playerView);
    playerView.requestFocus();
    mJSInterface = new JSInterface();
    mWebView = new WebView(this);

    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    layout.addView(mWebView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            Gravity.NO_GRAVITY));
    // Basic settings of WebView.

    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    });


    pv = new PrintView(this, null);
    layout.addView(pv, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            Gravity.NO_GRAVITY));
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(mJSInterface, "UnityInterface");
    pv.wev.addJavascriptInterface(mJSInterface, "UnityInterface");
    // Start in invisible state.
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

// reezo take picture
public void takePictureByCamera() {
    /*
     * //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
     * "/CameraImages/example.jpg"; //File file = new File("image.jpg");
     * //Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file ); Intent cameraIntent = new
     * Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
     * //cameraIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
     * startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
     */

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomCameraActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

// reezo open gallery
public void selectImageFromGallery() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
}

public void updateWebView(final String lastRequestedUrl,
        final boolean loadRequest, final boolean visibility,
        final int leftMargin, final int topMargin, final int rightMargin,
        final int bottomMargin) {
    // Process load requests.
    if (lastRequestedUrl != null && (loadRequest || !mInitialLoad)) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.e("lastRequestedUrl", lastRequestedUrl);

                Log.e("cookie", "URL: " + lastRequestedUrl);
                Log.e("cookie", "RETRIEVE COOKIES FROM COOKIESTORE:");

                CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager
                        .createInstance(mWebView.getContext());
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
                cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();

                List<Cookie> cookies = mHttpclient.getCookieStore()
                        .getCookies();
                if (cookies != null) {
                    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                        String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "="
                                + cookie.getValue() + "; domain="
                                + cookie.getDomain();
                        cookieManager.setCookie(cookie.getDomain(),
                                cookieString);
                        Log.e("cookie", "  --" + cookie.getDomain() + " : "
                                + cookieString);
                    }
                }

                cookieSyncManager.sync();

                Log.e("cookie", "NOW! WEBVIEW URL=" + lastRequestedUrl);
                mWebView.loadUrl(lastRequestedUrl);

                isWebsiteLoaded = true;
                // mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

            }
        });
        mInitialLoad = true;
    }
    // Process changes in margin amounts
    if (leftMargin != mLeftMargin || topMargin != mTopMargin
            || rightMargin != mRightMargin || bottomMargin != mBottomMargin) {
        mLeftMargin = leftMargin;
        mTopMargin = topMargin;
        mRightMargin = rightMargin;
        mBottomMargin = bottomMargin;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Apply a new layout to the WebView.
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
                params.setMargins(mLeftMargin, mTopMargin, mRightMargin,
                        mBottomMargin);
                mWebView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
    }

    // Process changes in visibility.
    if (visibility != (mWebView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (visibility) {
                    // Show and set focus.
                    mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    mWebView.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    // Hide.
                    mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

public void setCookie(String cookie) {
    Log.e("cookie", "FROM UNITY: setCookie(): OBSOLATE!!!" + cookie);
    this.mCookie = cookie;
}

// reezo call javascript function
public void callJavascriptFunction(final String unityMessage) {
    Log.e("unity Message", unityMessage);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(" + unityMessage + ")");
        }
    });

}

public String getPollDeviceAttitude() {

    return Constant.rotationValueForCamera;
}

public int getImagePickerStatus() {

    Log.e("ImagePickerStatus", Constant.imagePickerStatus
            + "    mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm");

    if (Constant.imagePickerStatus == 0) {
        Constant.imagePickerStatus = -1;

        return 0;
    } else if (Constant.imagePickerStatus == 1) {
        Constant.imagePickerStatus = -1;

        return 1;
    }

    return Constant.imagePickerStatus;
}

public void loadPrintActivity(String printUrl) {
    Log.e("JMK", "loadPrintActivity " + printUrl);

    /*
     * Intent iPrintActivity = new Intent(context, PrintActivity.class);
     * Constant.printUrl = printUrl; Constant.isPrintButtonVisible =true;
     * startActivity(iPrintActivity);
     */
    WebSettings webSettings = pv.wev.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    pv.wev.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    });
    pv.wev.loadUrl(printUrl);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Show and set focus.
            pv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pv.btnPrint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pv.setClickable(true);
            pv.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    pv.btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("VIEWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW", "kaj korce..............");
            pv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    pv.btnPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("VIEWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW", "kaj korce..............");

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Show and set focus.
                    pv.btnPrint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //String mPath = Environment
                            //.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        //  + "/"
                            //+ "dse.jpg";
                    /*
                     * Bitmap bitmap; View v1 = pv.wev.getRootView();
                     * v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                     * 
                     * bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                     * v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); OutputStream fout =
                     * null; File imageFile = new File(mPath); try { fout =
                     * new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                     * bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40,
                     * fout); fout.flush(); fout.close();
                     * 
                     * } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // TODO
                     * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
                     * catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch
                     * block e.printStackTrace(); }
                     */

                    Picture picture = pv.wev.capturePicture();

                    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(),
                            picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                    picture.draw(c);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
                    byte[] byteArchadeImage = null;
                    try {
                        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        if (out != null) {
                            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                            byteArchadeImage = out.toByteArray();
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("MSG", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }

                    Document document = new Document();
                    try {
                        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                                new FileOutputStream(Environment
                                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        .toString()
                                        + "/" + "dse.pdf"));
                        document.open();
                        //document.add(new Paragraph("This Is For You!!!!"));
                        try {

                            Image image = Image.getInstance(byteArchadeImage);

                            image.scaleAbsolute(600,
                            800);
                            image.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE |Image.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                            document.add(image);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (DocumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    document.close();
                    Intent printIntent = new Intent(
                            VividViewerActivity.this,
                            PrintDialogActivity.class);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                            + "/"
                            + "dse.pdf"));
                    printIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
                    // printIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    // Uri.fromFile(new
                    // File(ur)));
                    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                    printIntent.putExtra("title", "vividworks_report_"+time+".pdf");
                    startActivity(printIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private int dpToPx(int dp) { float density =
         getApplicationContext().getResources() .getDisplayMetrics().density;
         return Math.round((float) dp * density); }

public void LoadPrintActivityWithOutPrint(String printUrl) {
    Log.e("JMK", "LoadPrintActivityWithOutPrint " + printUrl);

    /*
     * Intent iPrintActivity = new Intent(context, PrintActivity.class);
     * Constant.printUrl = printUrl; Constant.isPrintButtonVisible =false;
     * startActivity(iPrintActivity);
     */

    WebSettings webSettings = pv.wev.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    pv.wev.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    });
    pv.wev.loadUrl(printUrl);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Show and set focus.
            pv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pv.btnPrint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            pv.setClickable(true);
            pv.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    pv.btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("VIEWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW", "kaj korce..............");
            pv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

public void loadNewWebPage(String webPage) {
    Log.e("jari", "loadNewWebPage " + webPage);

    // Constant.printUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
    Constant.printUrl = webPage;

    pv.wev.loadUrl(Constant.printUrl);
}
  protected void onDestroy ()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
}

// onPause()/onResume() must be sent to UnityPlayer to enable pause and resource recreation on resume.
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
    if (isFinishing())
        mUnityPlayer.quit();
}
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();}
```

How the close buttons(in second image) take same position after back to mainactivity. Please help me.

**Solution From Me:**

Only change on the layout file.Here is the updated XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="Close" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnPrint"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn"
                        android:text="Print" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webViewPrint"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the details for the Button.onclickListener (print button) ? Do you call the setVisibility method ?

Comment: How about seting the visibility of your print button in the onResume method ? (print.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);)

Comment: Post your activity code!

Comment: Actually, half of those buttons appear. So, no visibily problem there.

Comment: I cannot help you if you don't show me more code...

Comment: @johann, i am giving you two photos and the activity code.

Comment: I've tried with your code and 2 activities, but both buttons are  displayed normally. Is your @drawable/btn an xml file ?

Comment: @johann, it's a image.

Comment: I've finished my day's work, sorry. I will check your activity in 2 hours (when back home).

Comment: @johann, thanks a lot. I will wait for your answer.

Comment: Nothing in the onResume(), onPause() or onStop()  methods ? Where is the implementation for your buttons ?

Comment: I just added onResume(), onPause() and onDestroy() method. I used button in this method "public void loadPrintActivity(String printUrl)".

Comment: @johann, I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: When clicking your print button, visibility is set to "invisible".  pv.btnPrint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   So when you are back to this activity ,it won't be displayed. Try to reset visibility in onResume()

Comment: @johann, plz check the second image, print button disappear, it is correct but the close button not show properly(missing some of it's portion of close button). This is the problem. Close button should be same as like first image.

Comment: Try to use View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE . Your layer seems to be broken

Comment: In where I will use this

Comment: Thank you everyone. I got my solution.

Comment: Can you at least give the solution for other users looking for the answer ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution. Please check. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/top"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn"
                    android:text="Close" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPrint"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn"
                    android:text="Print" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webViewPrint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using weight in your xml is wrong. when you are making use of weight, u have to set the layout width/layout height as 0dp

Comment: Please read my full question, then answer me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like :

```
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   pv.btnPrint.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Your pv view is defined outside the onCreate method, it should work...